# Prospects of teaching/learning elementary math with computed-checked type theory

Tags: proof-verification, foundations, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

I've read as much as I can understand about type theory and homotopy type theory (HoTT) and it seems like these are very promising directions for re-foundationalizing mathematics in a way where complicated math proofs can be programmed and verified mechanistically. Unfortunately, but not surprisingly, all of this activity going on with type theory/HoTT is at a graduate-level and above.

Would it be useful as an exercise to try to formalize my understanding of relatively elementary subjects such as calculus, linear algebra, geometry, etc in a proof assistant such as Agda and just ignore the more advanced aspects of HoTT? Or is HoTT only useful for super advanced math

Comment: It might be useful for you. I doubt that it would be useful for "teaching/learning elementary math".

Comment: In several ways, HoTT is *more* like normal math than Agda is (e.g. function extensionality holds). Developing any traditional math should only be easier in HoTT than in CIC, say.

Comment: Incidentally, there's nothing particular about type theory that makes machine-checked proofs possible. There are set-theory-based proof assistants such as Mizar. Also ones that are type-theory-based, but on *non-dependent* type theories, such as Isabelle/HOL. That said, formalizing any non-trivial chunk of mathematics ("elementary" or otherwise) is a challenging task in any of these proof assistants. Formalizing calculus would not be the task of a weekend but of many months, and that's assuming you're already familiar with the system you are using.

Comment: "teaching/learning elementary mathematics" has several centuries of success and resources behind it. Given that, though, you are welcome to try alternate approaches by yourself. Be prepared for a lot of extra very difficult work.

Comment: @DerekElkins Surely formalizing all of calculus would be a massive undertaking, but one could formalize the basics in a synthetic way right? If I wanted to formalize an entire field of math from a few foundational axioms, that would of course take a large team of people working a long time. 


However, in a traditional programming language I can import and use a function that is a black box to me. Can I do the same with a proof assistant? Just add axioms and develop them as proved theorems later, drastically improving the rate of progress?

Comment: @BrandonBrown Can you point to a synthetic axiomatization of "basic" calculus that you think would be appropriate for your use case? As for your question about "importing" theorems, yes and no. In dependent type theories like Agda, theorems compute and this can impact how much you need to prove yourself. This means, in Agda, imported theorems are not black boxes, hence the `abstract` keyword. More generally, the ease of proving things depends on the definitions and the infrastructure you build. A good illustration of this is proving in Agda two ring expressions, such as...

Comment: ... $x^2+2x+1$ and $(x+1)^2$, equal in terms of the ring axioms (assuming the coefficients have a decidable equality). I strongly recommend trying this yourself (assuming/once you're familiar with proving things in Agda in general). It is a painful experience particularly for more complicated expressions. However, with some care and a bit of non-obvious shovel work, you can make such theorems almost trivial. (This is how the `ring` tactic works.) Chapter 4 of [Mathematical Components](https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/book.pdf) partially explains and demonstrates this mindset at a small scale.

Comment: Nevertheless, while I think it is very easy to underestimate how much work formalization (let alone well-designed formalization) is and how much other math even "elementary" math topics rest upon, I do think it is worth your time to do the exercise for yourself and see what happens. There are some approaches and insights that mechanization leads to relatively naturally, that appear to be easily missed otherwise. Mechanized proofs suggest a somewhat different aesthetic as well that puts a new perspective on the goals of doing mathematics.